# Programmatically close a window made with `racket/gui` (to stop a `timer%`)

Tags: user-interface, window, racket, window-managers

Racket programs that use `racket/gui` run until all of the windows are closed. This makes it easy to write a program like:

```
#lang racket/gui
(define window (new frame% [label "Hello"] [width 100] [height 100]))
(send window show #t)
```

And now the program will continue to run until the window is closed.

However, it sometimes makes sense to close a window programmatically, for example, if I want a countdown that will close the window and finish after the countdown is done.

As far as I can tell though, the only way to 'close' a window is the `show` method:

```
(send window show #f)
```

This however only stops the window from being displayed, but does not actually close the window. Normally, this is good enough and the program exits, like in this example:

```
#lang racket/gui
(define window (new frame% [label "hello"]))
(send window show #f)
```

However, if the program has a timer, it will not exit until the timer finishes. You can set a callback in the window `on-close`, but this is only called when the window is actually closed, not when its hidden with `show`. For example, this program will not get stuck:

```
#lang racket/gui
(define window
  (new (class frame%
         (super-new [label "hello"])
         (define timer
           (new timer%
                [interval 1000]
                [notify-callback (λ x (displayln "ding"))]))
         (define/augment (on-close)
           (send timer stop)))))

(send window show #f)
```

So, is there a way to either figure out when a window is hidden (via the `show`) function or programmatically close the window? If neither is the case, is overwriting the `show` method to stop the timer myself a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are subclassing the `frame%` class anyway, you can override the [`show`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/window___.html?q=show#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._window~3c~25~3e%29._show%29%29) method<sup>1</sup> to stop the timer whenever the window is closed. (Do remember to restart it when the window reopens if that is important to you.)

```
(define/override (show show?)
  (unless show?
    (send timer stop))
  (super show show?))
```

Making your overall class look something like:

```
#lang racket/gui
(define window
  (new (class frame%
         (super-new [label "hello"])
         (define timer
           (new timer%
                [interval 1000]
                [notify-callback (λ x (displayln "ding"))]))
         (define/augment (on-close)
           (send timer stop))
         (define/override (show show?)
           (unless show?
             (send timer stop))
           (super show show?)))))

(send window show #f)
```

Now your program will terminate.

<sub><sup>1</sup>There is a [`on-superwindow-show`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/window___.html?q=on-superwindow#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._window~3c~25~3e%29._on-superwindow-show%29%29) method, but it does not seem to always run when `show` is called.</sub>